# Can't change keyboard layout in opened Application menu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When Application menu is opened, it's not possible to switch input language, so you should close it, switch, and open again. 
Screenshot shortcut is not working in this mode too.

I use secondary language with cyrillic letters, guess I could miss some settings for it, inasmuch as Android Studio hotkeys work only with primary english keyboard.

[image: Apps menu]

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @RolandiXor how to change keyboard layout? It's seems to be bug thought.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to how X (the display server of most Linux distros, including elementary) works. What also do not work when the application menu is opened, for example, are global multimedia hotkeys.